# Kernel Driver Procedure Not Found

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kernel-module

I have recently developed and tested a kernel driver in windows using visual studio. The Driver itself is nothing but a notifier which prints info about created processes. I have already tested the code on a Windows 10 x64 machine by putting the Windows 10 x64 VM into test mode and installing the driver as a service. It works just as it should.

However I want to test this driver code on multiple windows os versions. The problem is whenever I follow the same steps on Windows 2012 Server R2 x64, Windows 7 x64, Windows 8.1 x64 all of them throw the same error.

[Procedure Not Found Error:127](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dL5v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely calling a function that is not available on older versions of Windows.

Open the driver in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on one of the systems where it fails.